# Getting result in list of lists instead of single list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm taking a column from sql db and putting in a df. I want to pass those a list so I added to tolist() function and I'm getting a list of lists which is not the result I expected.

eg: Data from sql

abc@gmail.com
bcd@gmail.com
.
.
I passed the above result to df then
`df = df.values.tolist()`
and the results look like [['abc@gmail.com'],['bcd@gmail.com']]
but I want the result to look like ['abc@gmail.com','bcd@gmail.com']

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your problem is hard to understand/reproduce, please review these resources: [mcve], [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a nested list.

```
A = [['abc@gmail.com'],['bcd@gmail.com']]
```

What you can do is flatten the list.

```
import numpy as np
list(np.array(A).flat)
```

Comment: I just did 
df = list(client.query(sql)) and it worked for me. thank you